# MySQL: how to assign same ID for records with close timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table  with timestamp column t. I need to create another integer column (groupId) which will have the same value for records with timestamp with 
 less then 3 sec difference. My version of MySQL has no window function support. This is the expected output in 2nd column:

```
+---------------------+--------+
|  t                  | groupId|
+---------------------+--------+
| 2017-06-17 18:15:13 |      1 |
| 2017-06-17 18:15:14 |      1 |
| 2017-06-17 20:30:06 |      2 |
| 2017-06-17 20:30:07 |      2 |
| 2017-06-17 22:44:58 |      3 |
| 2017-06-17 22:44:59 |      3 |
| 2017-06-17 23:59:50 |      4 |
| 2017-06-17 23:59:51 |      4 |
```

I tried to use self-join and TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,t1,t2) <3

but I do not know how to generate the unique groupId.

P.S.
It is guaranteed by the nature of data what there is no continues  range which spans > 3 sec

Comment: What if there are 100 records which follow each other with 1 second difference, so that the difference between the first and the last of those records is 100. Should they still have all the same groupId?

Comment: Looking at the expected output it's absolutely unclear what you want! Why don't you create an SQL Fiddle with your data and query?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using variables.

```
select tm 
,@diff:=timestampdiff(second,@prev,tm)
,@prev:=tm
,@grp:=case when @diff<3 or @diff is null then @grp else @grp+1 end as groupID
from t
cross join (select @prev:='',@diff:=0,@grp:=1) r
order by tm
```

Answer (score 1):

For this, I believe that you need to create a stored procedure that first sort your table by the column t (timestamp) and then goes through it grouping and assigning the groupId accordingly.... in this case you can use your own counter as groupID.

What it is important here, is how you split the time into frames of 2 seconds, you could end with different results depending of your point of reference...

Answer (score 0):

This query puts every record in the same group when the previous record is just 3 seconds before:

```
UPDATE t
JOIN (
SELECT 
t.* 
, @gid := IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @prev, t) > 3, @gid + 1, @gid) AS gid
, @prev := t
FROM t
, (SELECT @prev := NULL, @gid := 1) v
ORDER BY t
) sq ON t.t = sq.t
SET t.groupId = sq.gid;
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a97e11/1/0)
- learn more about user-defined variables [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html)

Answer (score 0):

This query will work in Oracle sql:

```
select  * 
from (
    select  e.*,
            rank() over (partition by trunc(hiredate,'mi') order by trunc(hiredate,'mi') desc) MINu  
    from emp e
)
```