# Similar SQLs with session variable produce different result

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

MariaDB 10.1.18

Table P (id int AUTO_INCREMENT, rownum int, code int, s int, PRIMARY KEY(id));

```
select id, rownum, code, s from P order by id;
+----+--------+------+------+
| id | rownum | code | s    |
+----+--------+------+------+
|  1 |      1 |    5 |    1 |
|  2 |      2 |    5 |    1 | 
|  3 |      3 |    5 |    1 |
|  4 |      4 |    5 |    1 |
|  5 |      5 |    5 |    1 |
|  6 |      6 |    7 |    1 |
|  7 |      7 |    7 |    1 |
|  8 |      8 |    7 |    1 |
|  9 |      9 |    7 |    1 |
| 10 |     10 |    7 |    1 |
+----+--------+------+------+
```

**Issue:** the following 2 queries are very similar: 1st query join on id, 2nd join on rownum; the id and rownum columns are having the same values (see table above), but the query result is different in calculated column N:

Query 1: join on id column

```
SELECT P.id, P.rownum, P2.s,
IF(P2.s IS NULL, @val:=@val+1, @val) as N
FROM  P CROSS JOIN (SELECT @val:=0) init
LEFT JOIN P P2
ON (P.id+1=P2.id AND  P.s=1 AND  P2.s=1 AND P.code = P2.code)
ORDER BY P.id;

+----+--------+------+------+
| id | rownum | s    | N    |
+----+--------+------+------+
|  1 |      1 |    1 | 0    |
|  2 |      2 |    1 | 0    |
|  3 |      3 |    1 | 0    |
|  4 |      4 |    1 | 0    |
|  5 |      5 | NULL | 1    |
|  6 |      6 |    1 | 1    |
|  7 |      7 |    1 | 1    |
|  8 |      8 |    1 | 1    |
|  9 |      9 |    1 | 1    |
| 10 |     10 | NULL | 2    |
+----+--------+------+------+
```

Query 2: join on rownum column

```
SELECT P.id, P.rownum, P2.s,
IF(P2.s IS NULL, @val:=@val+1, @val) as N
FROM  P CROSS JOIN (SELECT @val:=0) init
LEFT JOIN P P2
ON (P.rownum+1=P2.rownum AND  P.s=1 AND  P2.s=1 AND P.code = P2.code)
ORDER BY P.id;

+----+--------+------+------+
| id | rownum | s    | N    |
+----+--------+------+------+
|  1 |      1 |    1 |    0 |
|  2 |      2 |    1 |    0 |
|  3 |      3 |    1 |    0 |
|  4 |      4 |    1 |    0 |
|  5 |      5 | NULL |    1 |
|  6 |      6 |    1 |    0 |
|  7 |      7 |    1 |    0 |
|  8 |      8 |    1 |    0 |
|  9 |      9 |    1 |    0 |
| 10 |     10 | NULL |    2 |
+----+--------+------+------+
```

Comment: I don't think I have ever seen an example of row_number simulation where there is a join involved. In your examples the order by seems to sort the result set and does not participate in the generation of n. The second query can be made to work in the same way as the first by adding an index on rownum (or conversely removing the primary key). Parking the select..left join in a sub query and then cross joining to create n doesn't help. What is your desired outcome - perhaps there is another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explicitly documented both in [MariaDB knowledge base](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/user-defined-variables/) and [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html), you should not read a user-defined variable and set its value in the same statement, unless this statement is `SET`. For other statements it is unsafe and the result is not guaranteed, as your example clearly demonstrates.

*Additional note: variables you are talking about in your question are more commonly referred to as 'user-defined variables' or 'user variables', as opposed to 'system variables', 'global variables' and 'session variables', each of which imply system-defined variables, either all of them or limited to the given scope.*

Comment: Does it mean what the answers here are wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45260291/mysql-how-to-assign-same-id-for-records-with-close-timestamp

Comment: Does  it mean what the following article is wrong: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/

Comment: Yes, answers / recommendations which use variables in such way aren't good. They _might_ work in some cases to some point, but they can stop working any time, in any MySQL / MariaDB version, even the same version that you used before, simply because execution plan for the query has changed because of a different data layout, or statistics, or optimizer bugfix.